# To apply different font styles to certain words in a Highcharts wordcloud?

Tags: css, highcharts, word-cloud

Following JS Fiddle shows font styling applied on certain words.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/7evd8tgo/5/

```
    {
      "text": "UNKNOWN",
      "count": 584,
      "color": 'green', 
      "style": {
        fontFamily: 'Harrington',
        fontWeight: 1200    //font weight has no effect
      }
    }, {
      "text": "OTHER",
      "count": 138,
      "color": 'red',
      "style": {
        fontFamily: 'sans - serif',
        fontWeight: 1200    //font weight has no effect
      }
    }
```

I tried this in Highcharts. But it did not work.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/7evd8tgo/6/

```
{
  "name": "LANDING",
  "weight": 18022,
  "style":{
    "fontFamily":"Harrington"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to apply different font styles to certain words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**API** doesn't say anything about `style` property of **wordcloud series** point: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.wordcloud.data

You can use `className` instead:

**JS:**

```
var data = [{
  "name": "LANDING",
  "weight": 18022,
  className: 'custom-point'
}, 
(...)]
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-point {
  font-family: Harrington !important
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lpuyt1s7/